# Tensorflow.data.Dataset.rejection_resample modifies my dataset's element_spec

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, tensorflow-datasets

I am trying to use `tf.data.Dataset.rejection_resample` to balance my dataset, but I am running into an issue in which the method modifies the `element_spec` of my dataset, making it incompatible with my models.

The original element spec of my dataset is:

```py
({'input_A': TensorSpec(shape=(None, 900, 1), dtype=tf.float64, name=None),
  'input_B': TensorSpec(shape=(None, 900, 1), dtype=tf.float64, name=None)},
 TensorSpec(shape=(None, 1, 1), dtype=tf.int64, name=None))
```

This is the element spec after batching.

However, if I run `rejection_resample` (before batching), the element spec at the end becomes:

```py
(TensorSpec(shape=(None,), dtype=tf.int64, name=None),
 ({'input_A': TensorSpec(shape=(None, 900, 1), dtype=tf.float64, name=None),
   'input_B': TensorSpec(shape=(None, 900, 1), dtype=tf.float64, name=None)},
  TensorSpec(shape=(None, 1, 1), dtype=tf.int64, name=None)))
```

So `rejection_resample` is adding another `tf.int64` tensor in the beginning of my data, which I can't find out what is it for. My problem is that this breaks compatibility between the input data and my model, since it depends on the original input tuple.

Furthermore, it also causes an inconsistency between the training and validation data. I was expecting to apply `rejection_resample` only on training data, but if I do that, the training dataset will have the added tensor, while the validation one won't.

So my question is what is this added tensor to the element spec, and if there is any way to *drop* an element from the dataset after building it. Thank you.

Comment: can you please share the code of your function for `tf.data.Dataset.rejection_resample`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let suppose I have created the same dataset as yours,

```
x = tf.random.normal((7000, 900,1))
y = tf.random.normal((7000, 900,1))
z = tf.random.uniform((7000, 1,1), 1, 2, dtype=tf.int32)

#Now converting it to Tf.Dataset object
dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(((x,y),z))

func = lambda x , y : (({'input_A' : x[0], 'input_B' : x[1]}), y)
dataset = dataset.map(func)
```

After mapping my `dataset` will look exactly like yours

```
<MapDataset element_spec=({'input_A': TensorSpec(shape=(900, 1), dtype=tf.float32, name=None), 'input_B': TensorSpec(shape=(900, 1), dtype=tf.float32, name=None)}, TensorSpec(shape=(1, 1), dtype=tf.int32, name=None))>
```

Now, I have to remove this last `Tensor`

```
disjoint_func = lambda x , y :(x)
dataset = dataset.map(disjoint_func)
```

Now, the `extra Tensor` has been removed

```
<MapDataset element_spec={'input_A': TensorSpec(shape=(900, 1), dtype=tf.float32, name=None), 'input_B': TensorSpec(shape=(900, 1), dtype=tf.float32, name=None)}>
```

Answer (score 1):

I can't tell you where the added tensor comes from but here would be an example how to remove/drop it from your dataset:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
# creating a sample dataset that's similar to your 'wrong' output
ds = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((np.arange(-10, 0),(tf.constant(np.arange(10)), tf.constant(np.arange(10,20)))))
# remove the new 'wrong' tensor
dds = ds.map(lambda x, y: y)
# check new dataset
for i in dds.take(2):
    print(i)
```

Keep in mind that this is a workaround and doesn't remove the source that causes the additional tensor